# Calling a Python function from C in an OpenMP loop creates a deadlock

Tags: python, c, openmp

I am writing a Python extension module in C (actually C++, but this doesn't matter) that performs some calculations in an OpenMP loop, in which it can call a user-provided Python callback function, which operates on numpy arrays. Since the standard CPython does not allow one to use Python API from multiple threads simultaneously, I protect these callbacks by a `#pragma omp critical` block.
This works well in some cases, but sometimes creates a deadlock, whereby one thread is trying to acquire the openmp critical lock, and the other is waiting for the GIL lock:

```
Thread 0:
   __kmpc_critical_with_hint  (in libomp.dylib) + 1109  [0x105f8a6dd]
     __kmp_acquire_queuing_lock(kmp_user_lock*, int)  (in libomp.dylib) + 9  [0x105fbaec1]
       int __kmp_acquire_queuing_lock_timed_template<false>(kmp_queuing_lock*, int)  (in libomp.dylib) + 405  [0x105fb6e6c]
         __kmp_wait_yield_4  (in libomp.dylib) + 135,128,...  [0x105fb0d0e,0x105fb0d07,...]

Thread 1:
  PyObject_Call  (in Python) + 99  [0x106014202]
    ???  (in umath.so)  load address 0x106657000 + 0x25e51  [0x10667ce51]
      ???  (in umath.so)  load address 0x106657000 + 0x23b0c  [0x10667ab0c]
        ???  (in umath.so)  load address 0x106657000 + 0x2117e  [0x10667817e]
          ???  (in umath.so)  load address 0x106657000 + 0x21238  [0x106678238]
            PyGILState_Ensure  (in Python) + 93  [0x1060ab4a7]
              PyEval_RestoreThread  (in Python) + 62  [0x10608cb0a]
                PyThread_acquire_lock  (in Python) + 101  [0x1060bc1a4]
                  _pthread_cond_wait  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 767  [0x7fff97d0d728]
                    __psynch_cvwait  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff9d464db6]
```

Curiously, this happens whenever the Python callback function encounters an invalid floating-point value or overflows, printing a warning message to the console. Apparently this upsets some synchronization mutexes and leads to a deadlock shortly after.
Here is a stripped-down but self-contained example code.

```
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
#include <omp.h>
const int NUM_THREADS = 2;      // number of OpenMP threads
const int NUM_BLOCKS = 100;     // number of loop iterations
//const double MAX_EXP = 500.0;   // this is a safe value - exp(500) does not overflow
const double MAX_EXP = 1000.0;  // exp(1000) overflows and produces a warning message, which then hangs the whole thing
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyEval_InitThreads();
    PyObject* numpy = PyImport_ImportModule("numpy");
    if(!numpy) {
        printf("Failed to import numpy\n");
        return 1;
    } else printf("numpy imported\n");
    import_array1(1);
    PyObject* fnc = PyObject_GetAttrString(numpy, "exp");
    if(!fnc || !PyCallable_Check(fnc)) {
        printf("Failed to get hold on function\n");
        return 1;
    } else printf("function loaded\n");
    omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_BLOCKS; i++) {
        int tn = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("Thread %i: block %i\n", tn, i);
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            //PyGILState_STATE state = PyGILState_Ensure(); ///< does not help
            npy_intp dims[1] = { random() % 64000 + 1000 };
            PyArrayObject* args = (PyArrayObject*) PyArray_ZEROS(1, dims, NPY_DOUBLE, 0);
            double* raw_data = (double*) PyArray_DATA(args);
            for(npy_intp k=0; k<dims[0]; k++)
                raw_data[k] = random()*MAX_EXP / RAND_MAX;
            printf("Thread %i: calling fnc for block %i with %li points\n", tn, i, dims[0]);
            PyObject* result = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(fnc, args, NULL);
            Py_DECREF(args);
            printf("Thread %i: result[0] for block %i with %li points is %g\n", tn, i, dims[0],
                *((double*)PyArray_GETPTR1((PyArrayObject*)result, 0)));
            Py_XDECREF(result);
            //PyGILState_Release(state);
        }
    }
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

When I set `MAX_EXP=500` in line 7, everything works without warnings and deadlocks, but if I replace it with `MAX_EXP=1000`, this produces a warning message,

```
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
```

and the next loop iteration never finishes. This behaviour is seen on both Linux and MacOS, Python 2.7 or 3.6 all the same. I tried to add some `PyGILState_Ensure()` to the code but this doesn't help, and the documentation on these aspects is unclear.

Comment: Hi, what is your question concretely ?

Comment: ah yes, the question is: why the deadlock and how to avoid it!

Comment: as far I can see, the deadlock problem only appears when the Python code produces a warning (in this example, an overflow, but there are various other diagnostic messages that `numpy` routines can produce). So in a sense, the specific way of causing a warning is irrelevant; I first encountered it in a python callback function that used x**2 with an input array that contained x>1e150 (doesn't matter why such large values are used!), and then reworked the example into the present form.

Comment: So, you know how to avoid it, you just need to know why it is happening

Comment: mm, I'd say I do not know how to avoid it in a general case - the user-provided function is beyond my control and could raise some warning for its own internal reasons, which shouldn't affect the correct workflow! Interestingly, if the user function just prints something to console at every call, this doesn't cause problems. Even if the user function raises an exception (and returns NULL to the C code), this is still fine. It's only this weird thing happening somewhere in umath.so (which, I believe, is numpy's compiled library).

Comment: I found a sort-of-workaround: if I call `numpy.seterr(all="ignore")` before the loop, this disables the warnings printed from within numpy, and hence the loop runs smoothly. Meanwhile, if I print the warning from the Python callback function itself, nothing bad happens, it's only when a warning is printed from within numpy C extension. I tend to think that this must be a subtle bug in numpy, but not sure..

Comment: Wow, now that is a very interesting turn

Comment: yes, this reinforces my suspicion: 
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5856
although it is about multiple sub-interpreters, not multiple threads, but the underlying issue is the way numpy _error_handler() fiddles with GIL in order to print the message using python warnings interface.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the problem turned out to lurk deep inside `numpy`, namely in the `_error_handler()` function, which is called whenever an invalid floating-point value is produces (NaN, overflow to infinity, etc.)
This function has several regimes - from ignoring the error completely to raising an exception, but by default it issues a Python warning. In doing so, it *temporarily* re-acquires GIL, which was released during bulk computation, and that's where the deadlock occurs.
A very similar situation leading to the same problem is discussed here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5856

My workaround solution was to create a lock-type class that disables `numpy` warnings during the existence of this class instance (which is created during the parallelized computation), and restores the original settings once this instance is destroyed. While not ideal, this seems to suffice in my case, though my feeling that ultimately the culprit is `numpy` itself. For completeness, here is the code of this class:

```
/** Lock-type class that temporarily disables warnings that numpy produces on floating-point
    overflows or other invalid values.
    The reason for doing this is that such warnings involve subtle interference with GIL
    when executed in a multi-threading context, leading to deadlocks if a user-defined Python
    function is accessed from multiple threads (even after being protected by an OpenMP critical
    section). The instance of this class is created (and hence warnings are suppressed)
    whenever a user-defined callback function is instantiated, and the previous warning settings
    are restored once such a function is deallocated.
*/
class NumpyWarningsDisabler {
    PyObject *seterr, *prevSettings;  ///< pointer to the function and its previous settings
public:
    NumpyWarningsDisabler() : seterr(NULL), prevSettings(NULL)
    {
        PyObject* numpy = PyImport_AddModule("numpy");
        if(!numpy) return;
        seterr = PyObject_GetAttrString(numpy, "seterr");
        if(!seterr) return;
        // store the dictionary corresponding to current settings of numpy warnings subsystem
        prevSettings = PyObject_CallFunction(seterr, const_cast<char*>("s"), "ignore");
        if(!prevSettings) { printf("Failed to suppress numpy warnings\n"); }
        /*else { printf("Ignoring numpy warnings\n"); }*/
    }
    ~NumpyWarningsDisabler()
    {
        if(!seterr || !prevSettings) return;
        // restore the previous settings of numpy warnings subsystem
        PyObject* args = PyTuple_New(0);
        PyObject* result = PyObject_Call(seterr, args, prevSettings);
        Py_DECREF(args);
        if(!result) { printf("Failed to restore numpy warnings\n"); }
        /*else printf("Restored numpy warnings\n");*/
        Py_XDECREF(result);
    }
};
```